# Convert value received in currency

Tags: php

I need some solution that I can print the result of the query `file_get_contents`, and it should be shown only what there is in parentheses.

See:

```
<?
$value = file_get_contents("url");
echo $value;
?>
```

The `echo` value is: **document.write('49,90');**

I need it to return only what appears in parentheses, that is, only the value, for each variable created.

I tried that, but he removed the comma as well.

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$value);
```

There will be several variables with different URLs. It would help if anyone knew how to simplify this too.

I accept suggestions for using methods other than `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Add the `,` to the allowable characters in your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `PHP.NET`:

> Tip: If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can choose
>   faster (albeit simpler) alternatives like explode() or str_split().

So... `explode()` version (`PHP 5.4+`):

```
<?php
  $price = explode("'",$value)[1];
?>
```

or your way fixed (replace anything that is not a digit or comma):

```
<?php
  $price = preg_replace("/[^0-9,]/", "",$value);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get value inside quotes :

```
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $content, $matches);
```

Or without regepx, classic way :

```
$currency = str_replace("document.write('", "", str_replace("');", "", $value));
```

Comment: your first example doesn't really return the value itself, but an array (I know it's obvious, but op isn't familiar with PHP, so doesn't seem to be an answer to his problem)

Answer (score 0):

If your output format is fixed you can extract value using `sscanf`
like

```
$output = "document.write('49,90');";

$value = sscanf($output, "document.write('%d,%d');");

print_r( $value );
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@technoknol/sscanfINPHP